# easy way change a control property by having it's id?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Is there a direct way to change, lets say a `Textbox` Text when  we know it is called `TextBox1`?

I know we can loop through it's container controls and find the control and then access it but question is, is there an easier (more direct ) to do this?

Looping drawback is when a form has hundreds of Textboxes on it.

I want this to be done using code behind.

Comment: you want to change the text of a textbox via javascript?

Comment: What do you mean `we know`?

Comment: Is this on the client side or the server side?

Comment: I misunderstood your question, so I deleted my invalid answer.  The term you might be looking for is "Reflection"...accessing an object via its name in STRING form.  With an asp.net page though.....I'm less sure

Comment: It still isn't clear how you want to do this, server side or client side? And when do you want to change the text when a user performs a certain action? More info needed.

Comment: Not clear, What about `TextBox1.Text = "anything";` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Page.FindControl()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw(v=vs.110).aspx) with the name of the control.

So for your example, access the Text property of TextBox1 with:
`((TextBox)Page.FindControl("TextBox1")).Text`

Comment: hmm promising, is this faster that looping or it does it behind the scenes?

Comment: I just realized you marked this as asp.net, you should be able to use Page.FindControl() in a similar manner: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I don't know how it works behind the scenes. It is likely as or more efficient, and more importantly produces readable code and is good practice to use language constructs where possible.

Comment: @Nick Here's the behind the scenes: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,8db4ff0bd144aa76 It does still have to loop through all elements

Comment: @Nick also you should change or remove your answer as it's for winforms  and not asp (as you realized). Also, I think this returns an array, so you have to call `Single` or `First` as well.